# I am not able to get the result of callback function outside it's scope

Tags: node.js

I am trying to Retrieve MySQL result outside the callback function scope but I am not able to get the result of the callback function outside it's scope. 
I'm using the npm `pdfkit` :

```
function generateExamDetails(doc) {

    const query = "SELECT rc_name, rc_empid, DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%M %d %Y') AS t_date FROM table1 WHERE pc_id = ?"

    console.log("query: ", query, " data: ", pcIDdata)

    const getDataQuery = (pcid) =>{

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
            connection.query(query, pcid, (error, result) => {
                if (error) {
                    reject(error)
                }
                console.log("Audit Report1 ", util.inspect(result, false, null, true /* enable colors */))
                resolve(result);
            })
        })
    }

    var outerheaderResult;
    getDataQuery(pcIDdata).then(headerResult =>{

        outerheaderResult = headerResult;
    }).catch((e) =>{
        console.log('e: ',e)
    })
    console.log("Audit Report2 ", util.inspect(outerheaderResult, false, null, true /* enable colors */))
    doc
         .fontSize(12)
         .text("Some text", 10, 80, { align: "left" })
         .text("Some text", 300, 80, { align: "right" })
         .text(`Verified by: ${outerheaderResult.rc_name}`, 10, 100, { align: "left" })
         .text(`Emp id: ${outerheaderResult.rc_empid}`, 377, 100)
         .text(`Verified on(date)  ${outerheaderResult.t_date}`, 10, 120, { align: "left" })
         .text("Organization:", 377, 120)
 }
```

And I have the error :

```
Audit Report2  undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'rc_name' of undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `getDataQuery` function is asynchronous so `outerheaderResult` will be `undefined` at the time that it's accessed.

You can move your logic inside the `then` block and just use `headerResult` directly:

```
getDataQuery(pcIDdata)
  .then(headerResult => {

    console.log("Audit Report2 ", util.inspect(headerResult, false, null, true /* enable colors */))

    doc
      .fontSize(12)
      .text("Some text", 10, 80, { align: "left" })
      .text("Some text", 300, 80, { align: "right" })
      .text(`Verified by: ${headerResult.rc_name}`, 10, 100, { align: "left" })
      .text(`Emp id: ${headerResult.rc_empid}`, 377, 100)
      .text(`Verified on(date)  ${headerResult.t_date}`, 10, 120, { align: "left" })
      .text("Organization:", 377, 120)

  })
  .catch((e) => {
    console.log('e: ',e)
  })
```

Comment: after moving logic inside the `then` my pdf file not have the result. PDF file is blank.

Comment: Do you also **save** the file inside the `then` block?

Answer (score 0):

From your snippet, `getDataQuery` will move into callback queue and last lines of function will be executed by this time outerheaderResult is declared and its value will null

`outerheaderResult` value will be null since `getDataQuery` is async function. ( You might not know, whether it will be resolved or rejected )

```
getDataQuery(pcIDdata).then(headerResult =>{

            outerheaderResult = headerResult;
            console.log("Audit Report2 ", util.inspect(outerheaderResult, false, null, true /* enable colors */))
            doc
            .fontSize(12)
            .text("Some text", 10, 80, { align: "left" })
            .text("Some text", 300, 80, { align: "right" })
            .text(`Verified by: ${outerheaderResult.rc_name}`, 10, 100, { align: "left" })
            .text(`Emp id: ${outerheaderResult.rc_empid}`, 377, 100)
            .text(`Verified on(date)  ${outerheaderResult.t_date}`, 10, 120, { align: "left" })
            .text("Organization:", 377, 120)
        }).catch((e) =>{
            console.log('e: ',e)
        })
```

It would be fine.